# Beginning with?

Tags: meaning

I don't understand this phrase "beginning with its development". What does that mean? I think "beginning with" does not mean as it normally means, which is " start with someone or something; to have someone or something be the first in a series."

> The skin of the zebra fish is transparent for its first few days of
>   life, ***beginning with its development*** in a clear egg, so the egg can be placed under a microscope, and the growth of the entire nervous system can be viewed in real time.

I suppose just "begins" seems much more plausible. ("begins its development")

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you have in mind:

> The zebra fish begin**s** its development ...

(notice the final "s" after "begin")

But this sentence does not use the present simple to talk about development.

---

In the sentence you gave as an example:

> beginning with its development = from the start of its development
>
> The skin of the zebra fish is transparent ... **from the start of its development** ...

It could have been said like:

> The skin of the zebra fish is transparent ... **from** **the** beginning **of** its development ...

Comment: The sentences I provided are correct, but I cannot exactly explain why :(

Comment: The sentences you provided seem okay to me as well :) . Could you explain the using of "with"  in the sentence I provided?

Comment: I cannot explain much. It is one of the prepsitions used with "begin": "beginning **with** me", "beginning **from** 5", "beginning **at** the train station", "beginning **in** the morning"...

Comment: Hi, Is this a reduced relative clause which qualifies the whole independent clause?

I mean : The skin of the zebra fish is transparent for its first few days of life, which begins with its development in a clear egg... (which refers to the whole independent clause "The skin of the zebra fish is transparent for its few days of life")

Answer (score 0):

The sentence is saying that it is the transparency which begins with its development in an egg; that is, the skin will be transparent starting from its development in a clear egg and continuing for several days.